# hook_inline_entity_form_table_fields_alter add custom field

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

Need some help with [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) hook function hook_inline_entity_form_table_fields_alter.

I'm trying to add columns to the table that is visible when editing a specific node. I have been able to add fields and got the content to print too, but I need to add a checkbox. I've unfortunate not been able to **find how to add other custom fields**, so I wonder if someone has used this function before?

I guess it would be possible to add a "checkbox" fields to the content type itself, but in this case its more like a function rather than a value that I want to save.

Best,
Fever

Answer (score 0):

Add the checkbox field to the referenced entity. Also, as an alternative you could use ief_table_view_mode module instead of hook_inline_entity_form_table_fields_alter and then set the fields that should be displayed in the table on the referenced entity in the Entity form table view mode.